# Subfigure captions appear too close together

Tags: graphics, floats

Is there anyway to avoid what is observed below with the subfigure captions appearing too close together?

I would rather not use the minipage environment as a solution.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{image1.png}
    \caption{Test 1 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get. I will keep going to show that in the second line.}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{image2.png}
    \caption{Test 2 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Full caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `0.45\textwidth` and `\hfill` between the two `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use a shorter width for the `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image1.png}
    \caption{Test 1 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get. I will keep going to show that in the second line.}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image2.png}
    \caption{Test 2 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Full caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Don't load `subfig` along with `subcaption`. Also specifying a fixed width like 50mm is not good, because you might exceed the width for the `subfigure`.

[image]

Comment: There appeared to be two copies of the MWE's code; I've taken the liberty of removing the duplicate.

Comment: I see, thanks ever so much for this solution. I had tried .45\textwidth before, but of course forgot to add \hfill to separate them so it didn't appear to be working.

Comment: This would work, unless you want the figures to be close to each other. I wrote a solution below where I don't change the distance of the figures, and just add padding to the captions. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246077/37274

Comment: @hadi To get the images next to each other, just remove the `\hfill`.

Answer (score 13):

You can change the style of the subcaptions using `\captionsetup` command executed in the preamble of the document.

To change the width of the caption, you would use parameter width as follows (takes 90% of the width of the subfigure).

```
 \captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.9\textwidth}
```

Include this command in the preamble of your document.

Note, that it changes style of subcaptions in the whole document. There are also several other useful parameters you might experiment with (like `margin`, `indent`, for more see subfig package documentation http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig, section 3.1.2 ).

Regards.

Comment: `\captionsetup` may be used locally too, within the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\subcaptionbox` command from the `subcaption` package.
http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{position=top} %if you want to change the position of the subcaption; default is bottom.
    \subcaptionbox{Test 1 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get. I will keep going to show that in the second line.\label{subfig-1}}{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{image1.png}}
    \hfill
    %\hspace{1cm}
    \subcaptionbox{Test 2 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get\label{subfig-b}}{\includegraphics[width=50mm]{image2.png}}
  \caption{Full caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

@egreg's answer works, but is more of a work-around than a solution. What if you don't want to decrease the width of your subfigure, and still prevent captions from overlapping?

The simple solution is to call the `subfig` package with `margin` options. Like this:

```
\usepackage[margin=20pt]{subfig}
```

This will add a nice padding around the sub-figure captions, and prevent them from overlapping. Use whatever margin value that you would like.

---

Then the following code will produce **sub-figures that are adjacent**, while keeping their **captions properly apart.**

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[This is the first long caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth] {fig1.png}%
    \label{fig:f1}
}
\subfloat[This is the second long caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth] {fig2.png}%
    \label{fig:f2}
}
\end{figure}
```

This is the **good** result with a `[margin=20pt]`:

[image: Using proper margin value for <code>subfig</code> package]

---

While the **bad** result (*without* using the `margin` option for `subfig`) would look like this:

[image: Without margin value for <code>subfig</code> package]

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version from original code. Just using `\subfloat` from `\subfig` packages.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Test 1 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get. I will keep going to show that in the second line.]
        {
            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{testing.png}
        }
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Test 2 - text filling out page so it is possible to view the how close the text regions get]
        {
            \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{testing.png}
        }
  \caption{Full caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you like pkg `subfigure`, you can use this simple solution:

```latex
\setlength{\subfigcapmargin}{5pt} % subfigure caption margin
```